# Create a stack implementation that handles the multi thread scenario

Tags: objective-c, stack

MyStack.h

```
@interface MyStack : NSObject

- (id)pop;
- (void)pushObject:(id)object;

@end
```

MyStack.m

```
@interface MyStack ()

@property (atomic) NSMutableArray *stackArray;

@end

@implementation MyStack

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        _stackArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)pop {
    id obj = nil; // can return statements be part of critical sections themselves?
    @synchronized(self) {
        if ([self.stackArray count] != 0) {
            obj = [self.stackArray lastObject];
            self.stackArray = [[self.stackArray mutableCopy] removeLastObject];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

- (void)pushObject:(id)object {
    @synchronized(self) {
        [self.stackArray addObject:object];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to read and well written. As far as I can tell, it accomplishes your goal in a very straightforward way, and should be very easy to maintain going forward.

## Does It Do Enough?

Overall, it's a very simple class. Are you sure there aren't any additional things it should do? I know in the past, I've needed to check the size of a stack (see how many items are on it). So a `-count` method might be in order. And maybe an `-isEmpty` method (though a caller could just check if `count` is 0.) Also, sometimes it is desirable to get the top object without popping it off. Many stack implementations have a `-top` method to do that.

You might also want to offer some additional initializers similar to the other Cocoa containers. Maybe things like `-initWithCapacity:`, `-initWithStack:`, and if you're feeling ambitious, `-initWithObjects:`.

## Error Handling

In the `-pop` method you check to see if there are any items on the stack, and if so, return the top item after removing it from the stack. In general a caller should be informed if they are trying to pop a stack with no items on it. While you do return `nil` it might be better to raise an exception in that case, similar to how an `NSArray` will raise an exception if you try to get an object at an index that does not exist.

Comment: All points taken. 
Objective-C is not very error-handling friendly when using exceptions. Passing an `NSError` object back is preferred more. I didn't want to get into that when my main focus was handling concurrency, hence this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Some possible improvements:

- There is no need to make the `stackArray` property atomic because
  access to it is already protected with `@synchronized`.
- There is no need to check `[self.stackArray count]` in advance because
  `lastObject` returns `nil` if the array is empty.
- You don't have to make a mutable copy of the array only to remove its
  last element.
- It *is* safe to return from within the synchronized block, see
  for example [Returning from method inside a @synchronized block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704400/returning-from-method-inside-a-synchronized-block).

The `pop` method then simplifies to

```
- (id)pop {
    @synchronized(self) {
        id obj = [self.stackArray lastObject];
        if (obj != nil) {
            [self.stackArray removeLastObject];
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

An alternative to using `@synchronized` blocks is to use
`dispatch_(a)sync` from Grand-Central Dispatch. See
[What advantage(s) does dispatch_sync have over @synchronized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599401/what-advantages-does-dispatch-sync-have-over-synchronized) for a detailed comparison.
In particular, quoting from @bbum's answer:

> `dispatch_sync()` is faster than `@synchronized`, but not by a generally meaningful amount [...]. Using `dispatch_async()` is slower than both in the uncontended case, but not by much. However, use of `dispatch_async()` is significantly faster when the resource is under contention.

Comment: All points taken, almost :)
Putting out my thought process for the decisions taken:
1. Made the `stackArray` atomic keeping in mind the future additions. It is easy to miss a check for simpler methods like `count`.
2. Kept the mutable copy because `push` was also going to modify the array. Keeping an immutable copy needed more maintenance.
3. It was interesting to know about `dispatch_async`'s use here. Though I would still prefer `@synchronized` because it makes intent of the code much clear. Thoughts?

Comment: @AyushGoel: 1) "atomic" only protects from concurrent read/write of the stackArray property (i.e.g the pointer to the array object) itself. Asking for the count, or adding/removing elements does not modify the property, so no "atomic" is needed. – 2) I do not understand your argument. stackArray is already a mutable array, and removeLastObject does what you need. There is no need for `[self.stackArray mutableCopy]`. – 3) I suggested GCD  just as an alternative, and because it is slightly faster. (If you ever move to Swift then you'll have to use it because there is no @synchronized).

Comment: For 2. Oops moment here. Forgot to modify it when made the array mutable.